# appending to an existing excel file using XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, io, apache-poi

I am trying to write a code that will append data to already existing excel spreadsheet. However when I run this code the file becomes corrupted.

In case of this code I am trying to add a spreadsheet, but i have tryed with cells in existing sheet to no luch and all the same error. Am I missing something, looks like i am creating an Excel adding some data then writing, closing it. and then just adding a new sheet to an existing workbook and writing it again to the stream.

```
public class PlayWithExcel {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet ws = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Initial Data");
    XSSFSheet ws1 = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Cross Referenced");
    XSSFSheet ws2 = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("HPD");

    Row row = ws.createRow(0);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Value");
    row = ws1.createRow(2);
    row.createCell(3).setCellValue("Address");

    try {
        String path = "C:/Users/Jenny/Desktop/Test.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    XSSFSheet ws3 = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("another sheet");


    try {
        String path = "C:/Users/Jenny/Desktop/Test.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people facing the issue when trying to write more than once. [This is a known issue](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49940)  in POI.

However I'll suggest you try to reload the file using fileinputstream when you write very first time and you need to reload access the file again.

```
try {
    String path = "C:/Users/Jenny/Desktop/Test.xlsx";
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(path));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you have a file, you're much better off opening from that directly rather than going via an InputStream, see [the POI documentation for details of why](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: Sankumarsingh, thx so much!!! it really worked! but I do not seems to get the logic of what i just did. How does the InputStream Helps me, it is for reading the file. would be helpful if you could explain.

Comment: @Leah-DinaCharnetskaya: Initially you have created a new workbook, so no need to load any inputstream, but when you have written any excel workbook, and if again want to work on that workbook, then you need to load that again. By the way, using input/output file stream a bit slow and memory consuming. It would be better if you use file.